# Proof: For any prime number $p$, there must be integer $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $x^4+1 \equiv (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)\ (mod\ p)$.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

This is a question comes from a book about **Number theory**, and the question is related to **Quadratic residue**.

I start with

$$
x^4+1 \equiv (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d) \\
\equiv x^4+(a+c)x^3+(b+d+ac)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd\ (mod\ p)
$$

and then

$$
\begin{cases}
a+c \equiv b+d+ac \equiv ad+bc \equiv 0\ (mod\ p)\\
bd \equiv 1\ (mod\ p)
\end{cases}
$$

and I don't know what to do next.

The **Legendre symbol** and **Jacobi symbol** Properties and Calculating is ok for me.

Comment: Hint: If $-1$ is a quadratic residue, then $y^2+1$ factors, and hence so does $x^4+1$. If not, then exactly one of $2$ and $-2$ is a quadratic residue, so that $4$ is a $4$-th power mod $p$. Thus factoring $x^4+1$ is equivalent to factoring $x^4+4$. The latter [has been done by Sophie Germain](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SophieGermainIdentity.shtml).